# Sticky section in SwiftUI scrollview

Tags: swiftui, scrollview

I'm trying to simulate sticky section header that PlainListStyle has in scrollView scenario:

```
struct MyScreen: View {
  @State private var scrollViewOffset: CGFloat = .zero

  @State var headerScrollView: CGRect = .zero
  @State var headerTop: CGRect = .zero

  var body: some View {
    VStack(spacing: 0) {
      HStack {
        Text("Static top content")
          .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 50)
          .background(Color.red)

        Spacer()
      }

      ZStack(alignment: .top) {
        scrollable

        tabHeader
          .background(Color.white)
          .opacity(shouldSwap ? 1 : 0)
          .rectReader($headerTop, in: .global)
      }
    }
    .background(Color(hex: "#F7F7F7"))
  }

  var tabHeader: some View {

    Text("My Header")
      .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 50)
      .background(Color.blue)
  }

  var topContent: some View {
    Text("My scrollable content")
      .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 200)
  }

  var scrollable: some View {
    TrackableScrollView(contentOffset: $scrollViewOffset) {
      VStack {
        VStack {
          topContent

          tabHeader
            .opacity(shouldSwap ? 0 : 1)
            .rectReader($headerScrollView, in: .global)
        }

        HStack() {
          // ... content
        }
      }
    }
  }

  var shouldSwap: Bool {
    return headerTop.origin.y >= headerScrollView.origin.y
  }
}
```

I'm trying to achieve this by defining my `tabHeader` view at two places - inside `scrollview` and at top of `scrollView` (in `ZStack` with `scrollView`) - once headers overlap, I just show top one and hide one from inside the scrollView and it actually looks pretty good, just like list sticky section.

My question is: can I somehow reuse same view to be animated/translated/updated in those two  locations (inside `scrollView` -> swipeUp -> static above `scrollView` -> swipe down -> inside `scrollView`), because right now, if there is any internal state in `tabHeader`, it won't work because those are 2 different views so all the state they have must be in their parent and passed as binding.
If that's not possible, can I somehow restrict view from having internal state by implementing some protocol or something?

[image]